# Adding Job to beanstalkd

Tags: php, ffmpeg, beanstalkd

I am using Beanstalkd for processing video files via ffmpeg.
I am using https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk PHP-Client
I am facing the following issues.
    a) sometimes job is not adding to Beanstalkd Tube,
    b) if job is added to tube sometimes ffmpeg is not processing as expected.

Any idea,
Awaiting for reply

Thanks in advance
Karthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three scenarios why a job can fail on put:

```
- "EXPECTED_CRLF\r\n" The job body must be followed by a CR-LF pair, that is,
   "\r\n". These two bytes are not counted in the job size given by the client
   in the put command line.

 - "JOB_TOO_BIG\r\n" The client has requested to put a job with a body larger
   than max-job-size bytes.

 - "DRAINING\r\n" This means that the server has been put into "drain mode"
   and is no longer accepting new jobs. The client should try another server
   or disconnect and try again later.
```

Most probably you have the second option, I think it's just too big. **The default is 65k.**

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I'm adding a simple Json object in the tube,
Consider i am adding a job to tube "ABC",
If haven't added any job in tube for past 1 hr and i try to add the job fails at first attempt.
If try it again immediately it gets added.

Comment: @Pentium10 : Is it possible to change that default value ?