# Is 'Pheanstalk_Exception' with message 'JOB_TOO_BIG: job data exceeds server-enforced limit' due to a single job or long queue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, queue, beanstalkd

I got an exception while adding many emails to the queue on a Laravel 4.2 app.

> exception 'Pheanstalk_Exception' with message 'JOB_TOO_BIG: job data exceeds server-enforced limit'

I am confused whether this error is due to a single job or because the queue is too long. As the job is an email, I don't think this is different than any other email jobs which get added to the queue before it throws this exception.

Answer (score 0):

After sending the command line and body, the client waits for a reply, which
may be:

- "JOB_TOO_BIG\r\n" The client has requested to put a job with a body larger than max-job-size bytes. [protocol.txt](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/b7b4a6a14b7e8d096dc8cbc255b23be17a228cbb/doc/protocol.txt#L168)

see also: [Change max-job size of beanstalkd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782549/change-max-job-size-of-beanstalkd)

Answer (score -2):

it could be related to the queue driver that you are using, if you are using sync driver the jobs are executed directly on the main thread. if it is the case try with database or redis driver.

Comment: As the exception is Pheanstalk_Exception, it's obvious that I am using Pheanstalkd.

Comment: so, it is also obvious there is a problem with your driver.